# asp.net c# ÅÄÖ UTF-8

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem with special chars like ÅÄÖ they prints out like "Ã¥ Ã¤ Ã¶ Ã… Ã„ Ã–"

FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
title: 'We LOVE U!',
message: 'å ä ö Å Ä Ö',
filters: ['app_non_users'],
}, requestCallback);

Comment: I'm not having any problem with your sample code above ... the request preview looks fine when I run that in Chrome on OSX

Comment: Make sure you are editing the source code file in UTF-8.

Comment: Yes the page is edit in DW and set to Unicode (UTF-8)

Comment: How about the charset on the HTML page?

Comment: True, a .html page works fine. But when i rename it to .aspx my åäö become  "Ã¥ Ã¤ Ã¶ Ã… Ã„ Ã–"

Comment: I have included <%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8"%>

AND

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
But it dosent help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to do anything special to handle non-latin character sets in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715423/do-i-need-to-do-anything-special-to-handle-non-latin-character-sets-in-asp-net)